# how to combine multiple lines into one?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am trying to figure out a way of combining the below Dim statements into one line and maybe also combining Return dblResult into there. currently it is three lines and I have been told that it is possible but kind of lost of how to do it - can anyone lend a hand please?

`
Private Function CalcAreaFromRadius(ByVal radius As Double) As Double

```
    Dim dblRadiusSquared As Double = radius * radius
    Dim dblResult As Double = dblRadiusSquared * Math.PI

    Return dblResult

End Function`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this is a relatively simple calculation, there's no reason why you can't simplify this down to one line like so:

```
Private Function CalcAreaFromRadius(ByVal radius As Double) As Double

    Return radius * radius * Math.PI

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

While it's not a good idea to put a large number of stuff on one line, you can always use `:` to put two lines of code in one line in VB:

Canonical example:

```
Class Test
     Inherits BaseClass
```

is equivalent to:

```
Class Test : Inherits BaseClass
```

Of course, as long as you are declaring variables on a single type without an explicit initialization expression, you can do that in one `Dim` statement:

```
Dim a, b as Integer
```

Comment: This doesn't work for some newlines, at least not in VB 9.0. For example, `Get` of a property and the `Return` statement that follows cannot be combined like this.

Answer (score 2):

```
Return (radius * radius) * Math.PI
```